# Is it possible to join 1 table with 3 tables using hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, criteria

I would like to join 1 table which has id and 3 FK (foreign keys) to 3 other tables using Hibernate criteria. Is it possible? I enclose a picture, what exactly I want to do.
Naturally later I want to add restrictions for all tables. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Regards,
Piotr

Edit:
I realised that i need 5 tables, so I updated the picture. It describes all.

My code:

```
createCriteria().createAlias(Table1.FK2, "table2")
.createAlias(Table1.FK3, "table3")
.createAlias(Table1.FK4, "table4")
.createAlias("table2." + Table2.FK5, "table5")     
.add(Restrictions.eq(...)).list();
```

Comment: Short answer: *Yes*.

Answer (score 1):

Something as below

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Table1.class, "table1");
c.createAlias("table1.table2", "t1t2"); // inner join by default
c.createAlias("table1.table3", "t1t3");
c.createAlias("table1.table4", "t1t4");
return c.list();
```

where Table* are entity names

Comment: Is it 100% correct? Why 2nd and 3rd line both have "t1t2"?

Comment: @saba was a typo, corrected, this how we make joins with Criteria API, please try and verify

Comment: Could you please update your answer to the actual picture? I am still not sure how exactly it works.

Comment: @saba does [this](http://www.journaldev.com/2963/hibernate-criteria-example-tutorial) help you, also check for updated answer, comment added that "Table*" are entity names

Comment: @saba better post your entities